# Aggregating by some dataSources results in error: datasource not found or not readable

Tags: google-fit

Aggregating by some dataSources result in this error.

```json
    'error': [{
    'message': 'datasource not found or not readable:
                    derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.fit:Sony:H8216:cd3b0cfa:top_level',
    'domain': 'global',
    'reason': 'forbidden'}]
```

From the endpoint `GET googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources`, using the returned dataources that have the field `"device"` to request data cause the above problem. If I aggregate by any other data source, all works properly.

**Question**: What could be the problem?

**Example**:

1. **these work:**

- 'raw:com.google.step_count.cadence:nl.appyhapps.healthsync:walking step cadence '
- 'raw:com.google.step_count.delta:nl.appyhapps.healthsync:walking steps'
- 'raw:com.google.step_count.delta:nl.appyhapps.healthsync:HealthSync - step count'
- derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas'
- 'derived:com.google.step_count.cadence:com.google.android.gms:merged'
- 'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps'

2. **these cause the error above**

- 'raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:**Google:Pixel** 5:34812dc3:Step Counter'
- 'raw:com.google.step_count.cumulative:**samsung**:SM-R870:6130108e:Samsung Step Counter'
- 'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.fit:**Google:Pixel** 5:34812dc3:top_level'

```json
"dataStreamId": 'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.fit:Google:Pixel 5:34812dc3:top_level'
"device": {
        "uid": <str>, 
        "type": <str>, 
        "version": <str>, 
        "model": <str>, 
        "manufacturer": <str>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a data source with that id definitely returned by a call to https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources (passing the same OAuth scopes)?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes.

Comment: could you try again and see if this is still an issue?